# FuzzyQuery and BooleanQuery

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I work with Hibernate Search 3.1.1.GA.

I am trying my luck at fuzzy queries. This query works (it retrieves records containing Shakespeare):

```
lastName:shakespere~0.1
```

But this one does not:

```
firstName:shakespere~0.1 lastName:shakespere~0.1
```

I create a BooleanQuery and stuff it with FuzzyQuery instances with Occur.SHOULD. Wrapping the FuzzyQuery instances in BooleanClause does not seem to make a difference. Any hint?

Thanks,

Francois

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you need, try take a look at [MultiFieldQueryParser][1]

[1]: http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/MultiFieldQueryParser.html#MultiFieldQueryParser(java.lang.String[], org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer)